# Coldfusion Secure FTP existsFile errors when file doesn't exist?

Tags: coldfusion, sftp, coldfusion-10, cfftp

I am attempting to use the secure FTP ColdFusion functionality. I am running into an error with the `fileExists` function, only when using a secure connection.  Instead of returning "no" when a file passed in doesn't exist it instead errors saying:

> "An error occurred during the sFTP existsFile operation.
>
> The system cannot find the path {file name}"

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIbLo.png)

The regular FTP stuff works perfectly (same code as below but different connection).

If the file does exist, then there is no problem and the file is deleted and written.

I feel this is a bug, but I am confirming that I am not doing something wrong or missing something.

```
<cfftp action="open"
    connection="ftp_connection"
    server="#this.server#"
    port="#this.port#"
    username="#this.username#"
    password="#this.password#"
    fingerprint="#this.fingerprint#"
    secure="yes"
    />

<cfftp action="existsFile"
    connection="ftp_connection"
    remotefile="#arguments.remote_name#"
    directory="/"
    />

  <cftry>
    <cfif cfftp.returnValue EQ "Yes" or cfftp.returnValue EQ "true">
      <cfftp action="remove" 
        connection="ftp_connection"
        item="#arguments.remote_name#"
        />
    </cfif>

    <cfftp action="putFile"
      connection="ftp_connection"
      passive="true"
      localfile="#ExpandPath('/vctemp/#arguments.local_name#')#"
      remotefile="#arguments.remote_name#"
      />
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, have you tried the existsFile without the directory attribute? Or by executing a changeDir operation before the existsFile operation and ensuring your arguments.remote_name is just a filename with no directory?

Where you write "If the file does exist, then there is no problem", I assume you're referring to success with SFTP and not just the plain FTP test mentioned above? I read it as SFTP but if not then I'd suggest verifying the SFTP connection before the existsFile either by testing cfftp.succeeded returns true after the "open" or by using stopOnError="yes" when opening.

Comment: Yeah I originally had it without the directory attribute.  Adding that in was an attempt to work around this issue.  

Also I actually do check if the connection was successful, but I truncated the code for that as it seemed unimportant for the issue.